# JBoss Login Web Application error - Failed to parse request.: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query

Tags: java, jquery, json, rest, jboss

I'm trying to develop a login system, and I've followed Ticketmonster's structure. The menu container in main.html will be filled in only after log-in, and the content is filled with the login template, where the router immediately renders the login view, and the template is applied. Upon Clicking the sign in button, an Ajax request is created and sent to its service.

- This is the login function in the login view:

`

```
login:function(){

  var username = $("#username");
  var password = $("#password");

  var userLoginRequest = {username:username.val(), password:password.val()};

  $.ajax({url: (config.baseUrl + "rest/users"),
          data:JSON.stringify(userLoginRequest),
          type:"GET",
          dataType:"json",
          contentType:"application/json",
          success:function (userId) {
            alert(userId);
          }}).error(function (error) {
    if (error.status == 400 || error.status == 409) {
      var errors = $.parseJSON(error.responseText).errors;
      _.each(errors, function (errorMessage) {
        $("#error").empty().append(errorMessage);
      });
    } else {
      $("#error").empty().append("An error has occurred!");
    }
  });

}
```

- This is the service. Changing to @Consumes leads to the same outcome.

`

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response authenticateUser(UserLoginRequest userLoginRequest){
  User user = serviceUtility.getUserFromUsername(userLoginRequest.getUsername());

  if (user == null){
    return serviceUtility.badRequestResponse("No users with this username exist!");
  } else if (!user.getPassword().equals(userLoginRequest.getPassword())) {
    return serviceUtility.badRequestResponse("Incorrect Password!");
  } else {
    return Response.ok().entity(user.getId()).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).build();
  }
}
```

- This is the server error. Upon some research, I thought may be it's
  an escape string issue, but I don't see that applied in TicketMonster
  code, or discussed in the tutorial.

WARN  [org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8180-6) Failed to parse request.: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 38: localhost:8180/MCC2/rest/users?{%22username%22:%22wakas%22,%22password%22:%22Password%22}&_=1426754780833
    at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:859) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    ...

- This is the error on Firebug

GET localhost:8180/MCC2/rest/users?{%22usernam...2,%22password%22:%22Password%22}&*=1426757495550
400 Bad Request
19ms

jquery-2.0.3.js (line 7845)
"NetworkError: 400 Bad Request - localhost:8180/MCC2/rest/users?{%22username%22:%22User%20Name%22,%22password%22:%22Password%22}&*=1426757495550"
users?{...7495550
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data login.js (line 49, col 41)
var errors = $.parseJSON(error.responseText).errors;

- Switching the Ajax request's type, and the annotation on the service
  to POST, gives no error on server, but the following error in Firebug.

POST localhost:8180/MCC2/rest/users
405 Method Not Allowed
8ms 
jquery-2.0.3.js (line 7845)
"NetworkError: 405 Method Not Allowed - localhost:8180/MCC2/rest/users"

- I've placed a break point at the start of the service, and in all
  cases, the service is never entered.

**Update:**
Although I wrote this post with the GET request, I feel it should be a POST request, in which case the issue would be the reason for the Firebug error.

Also, I'm getting the following error when deploying my Application:
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Set, at table: User, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(userListIds)]

Here is User (exclusing the setters and getters):

`

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

@NotNull
@Size(min = 5, max = 16)
@Pattern(regexp = "[a-zA-Z0-9_]*", message = "Must only contain small and capital letters, numbers, and underscore!")
@Column(unique=true)
private String username;

@NotNull
@Size(min = 5, max = 16)
private String password;

@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 25)
@Pattern(regexp = "[^0-9]*", message = "Must not contain numbers")
private String firstName;

@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 25)
@Pattern(regexp = "[^0-9]*", message = "Must not contain numbers")
private String lastName;

@NotNull
@Column(unique = true)
@NotEmpty
@Email(message = "Not a valid email format")
private String email;

@Size(min = 10, max = 12)
@Digits(fraction = 0, integer = 12)
private String phoneNumber;

@Size(min = 1, max = 300)
private String description;

//  @NotNull <--commented since we don't have a setter
private Date creationDate = new Date();

@NotNull
private Role role = Role.MEMBER;

@NotNull
private boolean enabled = true;

private Set<Long> userListIds = new HashSet<Long>();

public void addUserToUserlist(Long newUserId){
    userListIds.add(newUserId);
}

public void removeUserFromUserlist(Long newUserId){
    userListIds.remove(newUserId);
}

public Set<Long> getUserListIds() {
    return userListIds;
}

public void setUserListIds(Set<Long> userListIds) {
    this.userListIds = userListIds;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public Date getCreationDate() {
    return creationDate;
}

//  public void setCreationDate(Date creationDate) {
//      this.creationDate = creationDate;
//  }

public Role getRole() {
    return role;
}

public void setRole(Role role) {
    this.role = role;
}

public boolean isEnabled() {
    return enabled;
}

public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    this.enabled = enabled;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String name) {
    this.firstName = name;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPhoneNumber() {
    return phoneNumber;
}

public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    User other = (User) obj;
    if (id == null) {
        if (other.id != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
        return false;
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "User [username=" + username + ", firstName=" + firstName
            + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", email=" + email
            + ", phoneNumber=" + phoneNumber + ", creationDate="
            + creationDate + ", role=" + role + ", enabled=" + enabled
            + "]";
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this line:

```
data:JSON.stringify(userLoginRequest)
```

should instead be

```
data:encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(userLoginRequest))
```

since you need to URL encode whatever data you are sending in the query string. JSONification may produce characters that need to be encoded before sending on the wire, failing which the server may run into parsing issues, which is the case here.

Comment: That fixed the error, but now: 
1. I'm wondering how come you didn't need to use that in TicketMonster?
2. I got a different error now: WARN  [org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8180-7) Failed executing GET /users: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ReaderException: java.io.EOFException: No content to map to Object due to end of input.

I'm getting the feeling that I should have been using POST all along. Changing to POST eliminates server errors, but gives me the Firebug error mentioned above. When should I be using POST vs GET and Consumes vs Produces?

Comment: I fixed the main problem. Escaping characters seems to be needed only with GET requests. Changing to POST got the userLoginRequest sent in the desired format using JSON.stringify(userLoginRequest). With POST, the main problems were 1. There was no dummy constructor in the Request class. 2. The deployment error I mentioned in the update (userListIds) seems to have had an effect, so for now I commented everything involving userListIds out, until I get the login system working. The Service breakpoint is breaking, and I'm working on fixing a new error. I'll update soon :)

Comment: On GET vs POST, GET is meant for obtaining the state of a resource. It is meant to be an idem-potent operation - it should not change the state of the resource. Multiple GETs therefore dont change the state, and may be used to obtain the latest state.

Comment: On using Produces vs Consumes, they're meant to indicate the content-type of the HTTP response body or request body respectively. You may use one or both of them in annotating a method, depending on whether the request or response has a body that need to be parsed appropriately. This is kind of necessary, since both clients and servers wont assume the content type to be JSON, XML, or any other content type.